# Node JS Call GRPC Server with custom headers

Tags: node.js, grpc

I am trying to call a GRPC endpoint but I want to provide a customer auth header. Where do I specify this?

```
var client = new proto.Publisher('127.0.0.1:50051',
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

var customHeader = { 
    'authorization': 'secret'
}

client.publish(data, function (err, response) {
  console.log('Sent');
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a `grpc.Metadata` object, then pass it as an optional argument to the method:

```
var client = new proto.Publisher('127.0.0.1:50051',
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

var metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
metadata.add('authorization', 'secret')

client.publish(data, metadata, function (err, response) {
  console.log('Sent');
});
```